# VueJS v2.6+ Reactivity System with Proxies & IE11 Compatibility

Tags: vue.js, internet-explorer-11, compatibility

According [ES6 Proxy Polyfill for IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285992/es6-proxy-polyfill-for-ie11) there are no pollyfils for proxies in JavaScript; how far would the new reactivity system in VueJS v2.6+ will support IE11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`V2.x` will not use proxies,.

`V2.x-next` (a parallel "experimental" branch) will 
and

`V3+` will likely make the complete switchable

Details & Source here: https://github.com/vuejs/roadmap

**UPDATE**

V2.X

No major breaking changes; will be maintained in parallel to 2.x with feature parity

V3.X

Possibility to swap the observer / scheduler with different underlying implementations. `E.g. ES5 observer for IE11 compatibility`, alternative scheduler to leverage requestIdleCallback for time-slicing.